# Trying to center button on page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, button

I have the following component code that I am trying to use to center a button on a page.  It keeps showing left-aligned.  I have tried using `<center>` tag and `slds-align_absolute-center`.  Neither change the left alignment I am seeing.

```html
<div class="slds-form-element buttons slds-text-align_center">
    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand"  variant="brand" onclick="{!c.createNew}" label="{!v.ButtonLabel}" aura:id="formSubmit"/>
</div>
```

Comment: try this class class="slds-align_absolute-center"

Comment: I just tried it again & it did not work.  Still left-aligned.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to remove class="slds-form-element" in order for the center class to work.

Comment: I thought you have removed already!. I will post my answer please close the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to align a button in the center. we need to use the Absolute Center class in slds positioned.

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">
    <lightning:button />
</div>
```

For more information: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/alignment/